# Ember data relations in single rest call

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using ember data and I have one model ie Husband with some relations like Wife(one to one) and Children (one to many). I know that I can provide links to that resources so ember load the necessary data for each relation. For example the list of possibles wife (Husband has just wife id).

Because my business scenario I want to load all relations in a single request ("../configuartion/husban_id"). I already build a rest service that provide all that information for an specific husband.

There is any way to tell ember data to load all relations from one single point in a single rest call?

Answer (score 0):

As described in EmberJS guide you could [sideload relationships](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_sideloaded-relationships):

> Sideloaded Relationships
>
> To reduce the number of HTTP requests necessary, you can sideload
>   additional records in your JSON response. Sideloaded records live
>   outside the JSON root, and are represented as an array of hashes:
>
> ```
> {
>   "post": {
>     "id": 1,
>     "title": "Node is not omakase",
>     "comments": [1, 2, 3]
>   },
>
>   "comments": [{
>     "id": 1,
>     "body": "But is it _lightweight_ omakase?"
>   },
>   {
>     "id": 2,
>     "body": "I for one welcome our new omakase overlords"
>   },
>   {
>     "id": 3,
>     "body": "Put me on the fast track to a delicious dinner"
>   }]
> }
> ```

For more complex scenarios you could also use `DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin`, which documentation could be found [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html). DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin allows you to define how a relationship should be serialized and deserialized. Supported values are `records`, `ids` or `false`. They could differ for `serialize` and `deserialize` if necessary.

In most cases like this one EmberJS [Guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/) and [api documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/) are providing all necessary information.